# unix ksh getting number of lines from file

Tags: unix, ksh

I'm using ksh and tested my script in a CentOS and Ubuntu VM and not having any issues. However when I migrated the file to a unix box the wc - l seems not working. Below is my script.

```
filelist=myfile.txt    
filecount=`wc -l ${filelist} | cut -d " " -f 1`
    echo "File count for $filelist is $filecount"
```

I have seen the permission and i has read for all users. What's causing it to have a problem in unix? Are there other ways in ksh to get the number of lines on a file? I'm thinking of using read line then just increment a variable for each as my last resort.

Comment: What output are you seeing, both for the script and for just `wc -l myfile.txt`?

Comment: I'll have to deploy it again to the unix box to test that out. But in my CentOS and Ubuntu VM I get the count and the filename

Comment: Btw, if you redirect from the file rather than passing it as an argument, you get *just* the count.

Comment: i.e. `wc -l <${filelist}` produces just `22` (or whatever the line count is). Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing appears to be wrong with your script, so there may an issue with your deployment. Perhaps a Windows desktop was involved in copying the text of the script?  In that case each line would now include a `CRLF` as end of line marker instead of `LF`.

For me that gives the following output:

```
: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Using Notepad++ I did an EOL Conversion to UNIX for the files before deploying it to Unix. Anyway I went to my last resort to just use read line and increment a variable as I'm running out of time